# np.searchsorted not working properly on netCDF4 array

Tags: python, string, list, numpy

`np.searchsorted` is not finding the right indexes but i think it is related to the type of data.

To me it looks like this function can't tell floats and strs apart but I can't convert the array to float.

```
 coord=Dataset(r"C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\coordenadas.nc",'r')
 lat=coord.variables\['latitude'\]
 lon=coord.variables\['longitude'\]
 lat=np.array(lat,dtype=float)
 lon=np.array(lon,dtype=float)
```

this gives me back the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\extract.py", line 41, in \<module\>

lat=np.array(lat,dtype=float)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: Variable.__array__() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

and when I try to make element I'm searching for into a float:

```
 coord=Dataset(r"C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\coordenadas.nc",'r')
 lat=coord.variables\['latitude'\]
 lon=coord.variables\['longitude'\]
 x0=np.searchsorted(lat,float(x))
 y0=np.searchsorted(lon,float(y))
```

this doesn't give me an error back but gives me the last possible index which is incorrect what I've noticed is that for negative elements this last method works just fine.

Comment: np.array definitely take arguments - did you perhaps inadvertently assign something to the name np? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Comment: what does `lat[:]` give you?  type, shape, dtype?

Comment: `lat[:].astype(float)` might work

Comment: Unrelated to the current error: the fact that all the paths here are in your site-packages directory is a little weird. Are you working directly in your site-packages directory? You shouldn't. That directory is for installed libraries.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my path problem i already solved it thak you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the error TypeError: Variable.**array**() takes no arguments (1 given),it is probably because you did not put [:] after the variable object.

Regarding the second part of your code snippet, it looks like you're trying to use the `np.searchsorted` function to find the index of a value in the `lat` and `lon` arrays that's closest to a given value `x` and `y`, respectively. However, the `np.searchsorted` function expects the input array to be sorted in ascending order, so you should make sure that `lat` and `lon` are sorted before calling `np.searchsorted`. Alternatively, you could use the `np.argmin` function to find the index of the element in `lat` and `lon` that's closest to `x` and `y`, respectively:

```
coord = Dataset(r"C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\coordenadas.nc", 'r')
lat = coord.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = coord.variables['longitude'][:]
x0 = np.argmin(np.abs(lat - float(x)))
y0 = np.argmin(np.abs(lon - float(y)))
```

Note that I added `[:]` to the end of `lat` and `lon` to extract their values as NumPy arrays, instead of as netCDF4 variables.

Comment: the array was sorted but in descending order so i sorted it and it worked just fine. I also added [:]. Thaks a lot.